# Log the color of an ellipse to a file p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to make a simple project in which the user has to select which text color looks better on a particular background. After clicking on the right background color, I should log the color and corresponding text color (0 for black, 1 for white) to a file.

This is what I have so far:

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(1200, 600);
}
function draw(){
  background(51);
  fill(0);
  wBol = ellipse(300, 300, 350, 350);
  fill(0);
  bBol = ellipse(900, 300, 350, 350);
  textSize(64);
  fill(0);
  text('text', 250, 320);
  fill(255);
  text('text', 850, 320);
}

function mousePressed(){
  var d1 = dist(300, 300, mouseX, mouseY);
  var d2 = dist(900, 300, mouseX, mouseY);
  if(d1 <= 350/2){
    console.log(wBol.fill());
    wBol.fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
    bBol.fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
  }
  if(d2 <= 350/2){
    console.log(wBol.fill());
    wBol.fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
    bBol.fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
  }
}
```

This doesn't work and I know 'fill' isn't supposed to work like this, but I don't have a single clue on how I should go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In p5.js, ellipses (and other shapes) aren't objects. The `ellipse()` function has no output, it simply draws an ellipse on the screen. Similarly with `fill()`, the function has no output, it simply sets the fill color for the next things you draw. So if you want to save the fill color, you should do it in another variable. You could do something like this:

```js
let wBol = { xpos: 300, ypos: 300, xwid: 350, ywid: 350, fill: 0};
let bBol = { xpos: 900, ypos: 300, xwid: 350, ywid: 350, fill: 0};

function draw() {
  background(51);
  fill(wBol.fill);
  ellipse(wBol.xpos, wBol.ypos, wBol.xwid, wBol.ywid);
  fill(bBol.fill);
  ellipse(bBol.xpos, bBol.ypos, bBol.xwid, bBol.ywid);
  //... the rest
}
```